# Checkstyle gives error NoClassDefFoundError: org/pache/commons/collections/FastHashMap

Tags: java, android, gradle, checkstyle

I'm getting the error below when running `gradle clean build` at `Task :checkstyleMain`. When I remove the `checkstyle` plugin and its configuration from my `build.gradle` file, it was able to build successfully. I tried adding `commons-collections:3.2.2` and `commons-beanutils:1.9.4` to my gradle file as dependencies but the error persists.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyUtilsBean.java:963)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.copyProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:391)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.tryCopyProperty(AutomaticBean.java:217)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.contextualize(AutomaticBean.java:249)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:455)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:186)
```

These are the dependencies checkstyle is using in my project (I ran `gradle dependencies`):

```
com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:10.0
+---info.picocli
+---org.antlr
+---commons-beanutils
+---com.google.guava
+---org.reflections
\---net.sf.saxon
```

This is a short snippet of my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'
}

group = 'com.example.project'
version = '0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
   compileOnly {
      extendsFrom annotationProcessor
   }
}

repositories {
 ...
}

dependencies {
 ...
}

checkstyle {
   configFile file("checkstyle.yml")
   toolVersion '10.0'
   maxErrors 0
   maxWarnings 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the dependency "commons-beanutils" is not able to pull its dependent "commons-collections".
So double check your build.gradle if you have not exclude dependency to commons-collections.
Your dependency tree:

```
+---commons-beanutils
```

instead it should be :

```
+--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:<version>
|    |    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:<version>
```